# Django: Recommended placement of template files?

Tags: django, conventions

It seems that Django doesn't have a convention on the placement of template files. What would be the most logical, preferred placement?

(Since Django stresses the interoperability of apps, I assume that the "best" placement would be somewhere under `/app/`; maybe `/app/templates/`?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As best pracice under your django project, the templates should be stored under `$project_dir/templates/` directory because by default django scans templates from every `$application_dir/templates` directory. That way you have a convention between your project and application directory structure. Hope that makes sense.